# Prove that the equation $x^2-y^{10}+z^5=6$ has no integer solutions

Tags: diophantine-equations

I have a nice diophantine equation which I tried to solve since march but no solution.
Tried modulo 11, tried to write it in some way to figure out a solution...
I posted this a few months ago, but it was removed.
The problem: Prove that the equation $x^2-y^{10}+z^5=6$ has no integer solutions( positive, negative). Maybe another idea if YOU have or a solution! I would appreciate it very much!

EDIT, Will Jagy: If $$ x \equiv 4,7;  \; \; \; y \equiv 0; \; \; \; z \equiv 1,3,4,5,9 \pmod {11}  $$ THEN
$$x^2-y^{10}+z^5 \equiv 6 \pmod {11}$$ which you can just check. At the level of school mathematics, there are two tricks I know for this type of problem. Neither works, but other people have found dozens to hundreds of tricks that I don't know. I also know of published problems with no answer because the book screwed up. Apparently the answer will be published in late September.

Comment: It's a youth mathematics magazine from Romania:)

Comment: I had already checked the equation mod the primes from 2 to 10^6, all have solutions.

Comment: Oh...I'll try it again, I must have made a mistake.

Comment: Can you please post a complete solution? What if they are congruent  to 0 mod 11? I didn't understand the answer with factorising from mister Lin :(

Comment: No, you had it correct, if $y$ is divisible by 11 it can work mod 11, because 5 is a quadratic residue. So, more work required.

Comment: @user85046 My solution is wrong, hence removed.

Comment: Why was the problem deleted before?

Comment: Because they said it was a homework...The question obtained a lot of negative  votes and it was closed. I hope we will solve it soon.

Comment: The earlier post was http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436282/prove-that-the-equation-x2-y10-z5-6-has-no-integer-solutions where several commenters were convinced that it sufficed to work modulo 11.

Comment: I don't think so. Can you show me that it works? If yes, then I really want to see this! :)

Comment: Did someone find something? :)

Comment: So, when does the Romanian youth magazine post the answer(s)?

Comment: Hello! I thought nobody will return to this question! Well...at the end of this month.

Comment: CFG, in that case post that as an answer here once it appears. Meanwhile, you would have a better experience at http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/ and/or https://www.awesomemath.org/

Comment: Avoid subjective titles, make them informative.

Comment: Modulo $41$ and $61$ there are solutions to the congruence. Modular arguments seem hopeless.

Comment: @WillJagy: Could approaches of the form $~(x^2-y^{2\cdot5})+z^5=6,~$ or $~x^2-(y^{5\cdot2}-z^5)=6,~$ or $~(x^2-1)-(y^{10}+4)+(z^5-1)=0,~$ etc. be of any help ?

Comment: @Lucian  I guess I will fiddle with it. An answer appeared in that Romanian magazine in 2013, so there are likely peculiar tricks (assuming problem correctly transcribed)

Comment: @WillJagy: Do you by any chance remember the name of the publication, because I've checked a few, but couldn't find it anywhere, either proposed or solved.

Comment: @Lucian all the OP said (in 2013) was "It's a youth mathematics magazine from Romania:)"  Romania was an SSR for quite a while, might be in Russian. I see Gerry Myerson linked a previous version of this. One possibility https://www.ssmrmh.ro/category/proposed-problems/

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

According to [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), for any prime $p$ and any integer a, $a^p\equiv a \pmod p$.

Working mod 2:
\begin{align}
x^2-y^{10}+z^5 &\equiv 6 \pmod2\\
x-y+z &\equiv 0\pmod2\\
y &\equiv x+z\pmod 2
\end{align}
Working mod 3:
\begin{align}
x^2-y^{10}+z^5 &\equiv 6 \pmod3\\
x^2-(y^3)^3y+z^3z^2 &\equiv 0 \pmod 3\\
z &\equiv y^2-x^2 \pmod3
\end{align}
Now, any square is 0 or 1 mod 3. So if $3\nmid x$ and $3\nmid y$ then $3 \mid z$, or $3 \mid xyz$.

Suppose that $g$ is the [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of $x$, $y$ and $z$. Then $g^2 \mid 6$, implies $g=1$.